# Bootstrap select showing duplicate fields in my form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-tags-input, owl-carousel-2

bootstrap select picker showing duplicates fields in my form when i was click the next-prev navigation .i am using the form in the owl carousel slider. Please anyone please help is this a owl carousel issue or it's a bootstrap issue. i am using rent it html theme but theme itself the issue is there.  Bootstrap version v1.6.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess u are referring to the thememeforest.net theme Rent-It. I've also purchased the theme and I met the same issue.

```
if ($().selectpicker) 
{
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
}
```

Just remove the above lines from theme.js or theme.min.js whichever you are using. I think it's initialised twice.

Comment: Thank you Arafat. You saved my day!! :)